# How to fire up Email Intent with File attachments from resources?

Tags: android, email, resources, attachment, email-attachments

I am a beginner in Android development.

I am trying to launch an external email application through an intent, and I want to attach a resource file to it.

I have been able to attach an image resource file through the Gmail app, but for some reason, the default Email app does not attach it. Here is the code:

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    emailIntent.setType("image/png");

String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.drawable.icon; 
Uri emailUri = Uri.parse(path);

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, emailUri);                        
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));
```

Also, even though it works for Gmail, the image file's name and extension are both lost when I send the file. Is there a way to keep all of the information associated with the file?

Help would be much appreciated!